# Periodic and odd function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations, periodic-functions

Problem from Georgian National Exam (Students know only pre-algebra)

Odd function $f$  with period $4$  is determined on the set of the real numbers. On the interval [0;2] $f$ function is given by the equation: $f(x) = 4x-2x^2 $. Find the set of solutions of the equation: $2f(x)\cdot f(x-8) - 3f(x+12) - 2 = 0$

Comment: seems like you need to do a couple of substitutions for $x$ with $x-8$ and $x+12$ respectively and work out the brackets. You will get a quartic equation.

Comment: I tried to use period and I claimed that $f(x-8)=f(x)$ . I did same thing for x+12 but I couldn't do something.

Comment: See my post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750806/find-2fx-cdot-fx-8-3fx12-2-0

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved this graphically after trying lots of things.

Answer (score 0):

So you substituted $$f(x-8)=f(x+12)=f(x)=y$$
so you get $$2y^2-3y-2=0$$
Can you solve this? then once you have $y$ try to find the solution of $$4x-2x^2=y$$
So you have two $y$ values, which will have two $x$ values each. You choose the solution in the $[0,2]$ interval.

Comment: What _were_ your answers? I seem to get results  matching the key, actually.  Also $k$ should be an _integer_.

Comment: @NikaChelidze please update your question with your work then.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. theseare the correct answers of the problem:  1+4k, 4k-1-sqrt3/2, 4k-1+sqrt3/2. I will edit the post with my work

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes it's right