# Find $2f(x)\cdot f(x-8) - 3f(x+12) - 2 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, periodic-functions

> Function $f$  $\in \mathbb{R}$  is odd and has a period of $4$. On a $[0,2]$ segment function $f$ is defined as $f(x)= 4x - 2x^2$. Find the set of solutions for the equation: $$2f(x)\cdot f(x-8) - 3f(x+12) - 2 = 0$$

So, here's my attempt: function has a period of $4$ means that $f(x) = f(x+4) = f(x+8) =  f(x+12)$. Also, from the fact that $f$ is odd,  $f(x-8)$ just means $-f(x+8) = -f(x)$ (I might be wrong here).

Now let $4x-2x^2 = z$. We get the equation: $$2z\cdot(-z)-3z-2=0$$ $$-2z^2-3z-2=0$$ $$2z^2+3z+2 = 0 $$

$D < 0$, so this doesn't have a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $f$ is periodic, hence $f(x-8) = f(x)$

Comment: Oh, that is correct... I'll try to solve with that information

Comment: This is wrong: $$2z^2+3z+2 = 0 $$ it should be $$2z^2-3z-2 = 0 $$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your solution, you make the following error

$$f(x) \space \text{is odd} \implies f(x-8) = -f(x+8)$$

This is not true, $f$ being odd means that $f(-x) = -f(-x)$, hence $f(x-8) = -f(-x+8)$

Now, since the period is 4, what we can say is that $f(x-8) = f(x-4) = f(x)$

Hence, replacing $f(x) = z$

$$2z^2 - 3z-2 = 0$$
$$\implies z = \frac{3 \pm 5}{4} = -\frac{1}{2},2$$

Now is where your odd function restriction will come into play

**EDIT**

Adding as it is not straightforward how to continue. Since $f$ is only defined on $[0,2]$, you extend it to $[-2,2]$ using the odd restriction. Hence $f(x)$ is defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}4x-2x^2 & x\in[0,2] \\ 4x+2x^2 & x \in[-2,0]\end{cases}$$

Now, if you solve on this full domain for the above, you have

$$4x+2x^2 = -\frac{1}{2} \implies x = -1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$4x - 2x^2 = 2 \implies x = 1$$

Now, since our full function $f$ is a periodic repetition of this, the roots will get repeated as well, and get shifted either up or down by 4 units each. Hence the roots will be of the form

$$x = \begin{cases}1 + 4k \\ 4k-1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 4k - 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Okay, so I've solved the equations $4x-2x^2 = -\frac{1}{2}, 2$ and got $x = 1\pm \frac{\sqrt5}{2}$ and  x = 1. Could you elaborate a bit more about how to apply the odd function restriction?

Comment: The answer given is the following $1+4k, 4k - 1 - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}, 4k - 1 + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}. k \in Z. $I'm not sure how to get to that.

Comment: $f$ is only defined on $[0,2]$. To find solutions outside that domain, you would need to extend the function to $[-2,2]$ and then use the periodicity. It's not as straightforward as solving. You will get infinite solutions

Comment: Extending the function to $[-2,2]$ would just be taking the negative values of the function, since it's odd. So we'll get values of $x = \pm 1$ and $x = 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt5}{2}$ and $x = -1 \pm \frac{\sqrt5}{2}$. Am I correct? Extending this to infinity using periodicity means just adding multiples of $4$... Still, the given answer confuses me.

Comment: The given $f$ is always positive on $[0,2]$. It cannot never be equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ on the positive side. Hence, the only way it can be equal is on the negative side, where the function will change, and you can find the new root

Comment: Try drawing the graph of the above, you will understand what I'm talking about

Comment: There's one thing I don't understand. In the $[-2,0]$ interval, the function is negative, so using the definition of the odd function $f(-x) = -f(x)$ shouldn't we get  $f(-x) = -(4x-2x^2) = -4x + 2x^2$? Why is there a plus sign in front of $4x$ ?

Comment: $f(-x) = -4x-2x^2 = -(4x+2x^2)$. So if the odd half of the function is defined to be $f(x|x<0) = 4x+2x^2$ it would make the function odd

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've been extremely helpful!